# Android : how to pass the default selected thing in to a new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gridview

In my Activity i have a EditText, ImageView and Button.I place a ImageView inside the GridView, When My Activity was loaded.

The Gridview First Image was Selected Default and i want to Enter the EditText name and pass both the EditText value  and the Default selected image( user can also Choose his Own Image if he dont like the default image ) to the New Activity

My Problem is User Enter the edittext value and he press the Button it pass only the EditText value not the default Selected Image, If user Choose the other Images in the gridview it pass both the ImageView and the EditText value also if he Choose the default selected image manually then it works Fine .

how to pass the default marked image  without selecting again  how to pass to another Activity
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My Code :

```
int[] images={R.drawable.menu,R.drawable.musicbox,R.drawable.shoppingbag,R.drawable.shoppingcart,R.drawable.wallet,R.drawable.weddingdress};
    int imageRes;

    public NewListCreate() {
    }
         public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
                 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_create, container, false);
        
                ImageButton done = view.findViewById(R.id.done);
                final EditText listname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.listname);
                final GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        
                final CustomAdpter customAdpter = new CustomAdpter(images,getContext());
                gridView.setAdapter(customAdpter);
                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        customAdpter.selectedImage = i;
                        customAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        imageRes = images[i];
       
                    }
                });
     done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
    
                    String itemname = listname.getText().toString();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(listname.getText().toString())) {
    
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), CheckslateHome.class).putExtra("data", itemname).putExtra("image",imageRes));
                        dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "List Name not Empty ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
                }
    
           });
    
            
            return view;
```

CustomAdapter

```
 private int[] icons;
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        public int selectedImage = 0;

        public CustomAdpter(int[] icons, Context context) {
            this.icons = icons;
            this.context = context;
            this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

     public int selectedImage = 0;
        @Override
            public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        
                    if (view == null)
                    {
                       view =  layoutInflater .inflate(R.layout.image_list,viewGroup,false);
        
                    }
        
                    ImageView imageicons = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                if (i < icons.length) {
        
                    imageicons.setImageResource(icons[i]);
        
                    if (i != selectedImage) {
                       imageicons.setImageAlpha(50);
                    }
                    imageicons.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                   // imageicons.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                    if (i ==  selectedImage) {
        
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                };
        
        
                return view;
```

Comment: In your CustomAdapter set default value as the initial value for "selectedImage".

Comment: Sorry Bro i am new to Android Can u Say how to do pls

Comment: Basically, at least as far as we can see on the code you posted, you only change the selected image on click from your grid (`customAdpter.selectedImage = i`). As such, if the user does not click an image, the selectedImage will not have been set. On your CustomAdapter class, you probably have a line like `public int selectedImage;`. Set the default value there - `public int selectedImage = default_image_id;` - or inside the constructor.

Comment: sry bro i forget to add tht line in the above coading..but actaully it was there as  public int selectedImage = 0; pls check the updated Code @LukeSykpe

Comment: Sry Can't undestand, i have 6 images in drawable and the detault first image is marked, if i choose the second image and i click done it working fine. if i didn't choose the the first image( bcoz it was marked right) so if i click done it pass only edittext value....

Comment: Is the default image the first one in `icons[]`?

Comment: s bro plz check above i upload the image Output

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question. Your problem is not with CustomAdapter, but with the Intent on button click. What is the default value of `imageRes`? Its declaration is not seen in the code you posted above.

Comment: Right, just change `int imageRes;` to `int imageRes = R.drawable.your_default_icon_name;` and you should be fine.

Comment: add default value to `int imageRes`, e.g `int imageRes = images[0];` ;)

Comment: thanks Bro it Working , But customAdpter.selectedImage = i; i want this one to be passed in my intent How to do that..without mentioning this ` int imageRes = R.drawable.your_default_icon_name;`

Comment: @damienG thx Bro, without this line ` imageRes = images[i];` is it possible to Share selectedimage with intent (   customAdpter.selectedImage = i;)

Comment: @damienG my images are in drawable so we use int imageRes = images[0]; if my images are in URL how to do that so only i asked..

Comment: @LukeSykpe  my images are in drawable so we use int imageRes = drawable if my images are in URL how to do that so only i asked..

Comment: You'll have to download the image. The easiest way to do that would be using a library, like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/). There's plenty of example code on their site to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

**activity_frist.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_one"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_natural" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_one"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Go to second Activity"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**FirstActivity.java**

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView img_one;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frist);

        img_one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_one);

        img_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img_one.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_two"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_two"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Second Activity"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img_two;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        img_two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_two);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        img_two.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }
}
```